# How discover what's the uuid of connect network from Terminal?

Tags: wireless, networking

I'm developing a little application in Python (at moment just learning) and I need discover what's the "uuid" of the currently connected network.

**I have the following script to return the default network interface:**

```
route -n | awk '$1 ~ /0.0.0.0/ {print $NF}'
```

Now how I can discover, from Terminal, what's the network that I'm currently connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given any information about your version or configuration, but if you are using a recent version of the network-manager package then you can use `nmcli` e.g.

```
nmcli con status
```

or to output only the UUID of the active connection(s)

```
nmcli --terse --fields UUID con status
```

or in short form

```
nmcli -t -f UUID con status
```

Comment: You're welcome - fyi since you mention python, you may want to look at doing everything via the dbus python API rather than breaking out to the shell